# Error can not call getNString() al capturar valores de BD

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación de una clínica privada y para entrar a la aplicación, primeramente selecciono el identificardor del paciente a través de un `JComboBox`.

Luego, tengo un método para llenar un `arrayList` con los datos de los pacientes para posteriormente rellenar un formulario con dichos datos.

El problema lo tengo al llenar este `array`, antes de llenarlo capturo todos los valores del `resultset` y en la excepción me salta este error:

> can not call getNString() when field´s charset isn´t UTF-8

Intuyo que esta excepción está saltando porque algún campo de la `BD` tiene un `charset` distinto, pero no consigo averiguar el porqué.

Adjunto mi fuente actual donde me está produciendo el error:

```
public void llenarArrayList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    resultSet = mysql.ejecutaConsulta("SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE NUS =" + jcNuss.getSelectedItem());
    int nuss = 0;
    String cadena = "";
    String primerApellido = new String(cadena.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String segundoApellido = new String(cadena.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String nombre = new String(cadena.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    int telf = 0;
    Date fechaNacimiento = null;
    Date fechaAlta = null;
    int medicamento = 0;
    try {
        while(resultSet.next()){
            nuss = resultSet.getInt(1);
            nombre = resultSet.getString(2);
            primerApellido = resultSet.getString(3);
            segundoApellido = resultSet.getNString(4);
            telf = resultSet.getInt(5);
            fechaNacimiento = resultSet.getDate(5);
            fechaAlta = resultSet.getDate(6);
            medicamento = resultSet.getInt(7);  
        }

        System.out.println("nus: " + nuss + " Nombre: " + nombre + " apellido: " + primerApellido + " apellido2: " + 
                    segundoApellido + " telf: " + telf + " fechaNacimiento: " + fechaNacimiento + " fechaAlta: " + fechaAlta+
                    " medicam " + medicamento);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cambia el método `getNString()` en esta linea `segundoApellido = resultSet.getNString(4);` por es `getString()`

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `getNString` y no simplemente `getString` en la columna del segundo apellido?  [La doc dice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getNString-int-) que ese método es para columnas del tipo `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`o `LONGNVARCHAR`. ¿La columna del 2º apellido es de uno de esos tipos? Otra cosa que se ve en tu código es que usas el mismo índice para recuperar el `telf` y `fechaNacimiento`. Y también tu código adolece de un grave fallo de seguridad llamado **Inyección SQL**, a través del cual te puede colar código dañino en el sistema, usa consultas preparadas

Comment: @E.Betanzos muchas gracias... vaya tontería....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas usando dos recuperaciones diferentes para tus filas.

```
primerApellido = resultSet.getString(3);
segundoApellido = resultSet.getNString(4);
```

Es importante usar el tipo de método acorde con la creación de la columna. El metodo getString se usa normalmente para obtener datos de celdas "CHAR", "VARCHAR","TEXT",... en general en celdas con un byte por carácter. Mientras que getNString se usa para columnas de tipo "NCHAR", "NVARCHAR",... En general columnas que soportan mas de un byte por carácter.

En tu caso seguramente la tabla está definida con codificación estándar y el retorno de `segundoApellido` debería ser `getString(4)`

Comment: efectivamente @Dubas ya me lo dijeron por arriba